# Flexbox space between with line between rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is a question I already have a solution to, but I'm wondering if there's a better way. What I want is to use flexbox to have rows of items with even space in between and a line between rows. The first and second example in the snippet below achieve this by using an `:after`, but I have to use a fair amount of CSS to hide it on the last row.

```
.item:nth-child(4n + 1):nth-last-child(4):after,
.item:nth-child(4n + 1):nth-last-child(4):after,
.item:nth-child(4n + 1):nth-last-child(2):after,
.item:nth-child(4n + 1):nth-last-child(1):after{
  display: none;  
}
```

Surely there is a better way (using flexbox) Does anyone know?

I tried using a border on each item but obviously this has space between them which doesn't work and then I would still need to hide it using `:nth-last-child`.

```css
.outer{
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.wrap{
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 4;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  display: flex;
}

.item{
  width: 23%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.item2{
  width: 23%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.item:nth-child(4n + 1):after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 500%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .item:nth-child(2n + 1):nth-last-child(2):after,
  .item:nth-child(2n + 1):nth-last-child(1):after{
    display: none;  
  }
  .item{
    width: 43%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .item:nth-child(4n + 1):nth-last-child(4):after,
  .item:nth-child(4n + 1):nth-last-child(4):after,
  .item:nth-child(4n + 1):nth-last-child(2):after,
  .item:nth-child(4n + 1):nth-last-child(1):after{
    display: none;  
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <h3>Working example - 8 Items</h3>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="item">Item 6</div>
      <div class="item">Item 7</div>
      <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <h3>Working example - 5 Items</h3>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <h3>Using normal border</h3>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="item2">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item2">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item2">Item 4</div>
      <div class="item2">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is four item for each row fixed or will change?

Comment: It will change for smaller devices, which adds more complexity, so I didn't include that in the example :)

Comment: If they go to be 3 rows in a small device, So we have 3 red lins? If it is i don't think your code is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `:before` and avoid the `display:none` rules :

```css
.outer{
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.wrap{
  overflow: hidden;/* will hide first row of item:before */
  /* flex: 4; i do not see the use here */
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  display: flex;
}

.item{
  width: 23%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.item2{/* just to do it different , don ' t mind that part */
  width: 23%;
  padding : 30px 0;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.item:nth-child(4n + 1):before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 500%;
  top: -30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <h3>Working example - 8 Items</h3>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="item">Item 6</div>
      <div class="item">Item 7</div>
      <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <h3>Working example - 5 Items</h3>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <h3>Using normal border</h3>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="item2">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item2">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item2">Item 4</div>
      <div class="item2">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**edit**

You can also set a breakpoint and use each item to draw the line

```css
.outer{
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.wrap{
  overflow: hidden;/* will hide first row of item:before */
  /* flex: 4; i do not see the use here */
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  display: flex;
}

.item{
  width: 23%;
  margin: 29px 1% 31px;
  position: relative;
}
.item2{/* just to do it different , don ' t mind that part */
  width: 23%;
  padding : 30px 0;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.item:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20%;
  width: 800%;
  top: -30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.brkpt .item  {
  min-width:60px;
  max-width:100px;
  background:gray
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <h3>Working example - 8 Items</h3>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="item">Item 6</div>
      <div class="item">Item 7</div>
      <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Working example - 16 Items breaking points every 120px average</h3>
  <div class="wrap brkpt">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="item">Item 6</div>
      <div class="item">Item 7</div>
      <div class="item">Item 8</div>
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="item">Item 6</div>
      <div class="item">Item 7</div>
      <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <h3>Working example - 5 Items</h3>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <h3>Using normal border</h3>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="item2">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item2">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item2">Item 4</div>
      <div class="item2">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought of another way. This is a responsive solution. I think this is the best way... 
To see 4 columns you need to click full page button

```css
.outer{
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.wrap{
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 4;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  display: flex;
}
.full{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  height: 1px;
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .visible-small{
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .visible-large{
    display: block;
  }
}
.item{
  width: 23%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <h3>Using extra div</h3>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="full visible-small"></div>
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="full visible-large visible-small"></div>
      <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <h3>Using extra div</h3>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="full visible-small"></div>
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="full visible-large visible-small"></div>
      <div class="item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="item">Item 6</div>
      <div class="full visible-small"></div>
      <div class="item">Item 7</div>
      <div class="item">Item 8</div>
      <div class="full visible-large visible-small"></div>
      <div class="item">Item 9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i said in small devices you will have serious problem with this method. I suggest you to use this image:

[image: background image]

As the bcackground image of total menu (`<div class="wrap"`), Of course with some changes related to the height of menu items.

```
.wrap{
   background-image: url(IMAGE-URL);
   background-repeat: repeat;
 }
```

Comment: I'm looking for a flexbox solution. I know how to do it other ways. It is easy to allow for smaller devices, there isn't any serious problem. I've updated my examples in the question. Thanks for your suggestion though.